# Many findElement in a row with xPath

Tags: ios, xpath, appium

Here is the screenshot of my app's tree :

Apps tree
[image]

I have a methode to get all of the TableCell. But how can I find the childs of my WebElements ?

I've tried this :

```
getMyTableCell().get(0).findElements(By.xpath".//*")
```

But this expression give me the UIAApplication (root). The .//* seems to search the elements from the root.

Any idea ?

Comment: post your HTML code here

Comment: It's an iOS app. The screenshot comes from the Appium Inspector

Comment: how do you access `getMyTableCell()`, could you share the code to it? 
+ `.get(0)` seems to be looking for elements under first table cell

Comment: This is how I do getMyTableCell() : `return List<WebElement> driver.findElements(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell"))`
And this is working